# Даны действительные числа x и y. Определить, лежит ли точка с координатами (x,y) внутри заштрихованной области

Tags: pascal

Задачу нужно выполнить на Паскале. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сравните квадрат расстояния с единицей (теорема Пифагора), а также одинаковы ли знаки икс- и игрек-координаты. Код за вас писать вряд ли кто-то будет.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что заказчик ошибся сайтом.

Answer (score 2):

```
(x*y >= 0) and (x*x + y*y <= 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x, y: real;
begin
  readln(x, y);
  writeln(x * x + y * y <= 1);
end.
```

простая проверка попадет ли в эту окружность

дальше добавьте условие попадает ли в области